# owin Self-hosting web api new relic monitoring

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-worker-roles, newrelic, owin

I just moved some of are web api from IIS web role to a worker role in Windows Azure and that is working way betting. What I want to know is how much better so, and before we using New Relic to monitor the web server. I have the agent installed on the worker roles but not getting any of the great analytics.

[(What I followed to make this work)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role)

So I was hoping someone could help me get some basic stats on how well my self-hosted web server is performing into new relic. I looking for throughput, response time, and log errors.

I [found something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490473/ignore-persistent-signalr-connections-in-new-relic) that seems to make me think that I could do it but I am not familiar with owin.

If anyone has some ideas on how to get this work that would great!

Edit:
What I am looking for is if someone can help me use the newrelic api ( RecordMetric(), RecordResponseTimeMetric(), IncrementCounter(), etc.) and hook it up in the owin pipeline to record throughput, response time, and log errors?

Answer (score 0):

The New Relic .NET agent gathers most transaction-related metrics within the context of the IIS pipeline.  The agent can get some basic metrics for standalone services like Worker Roles (WaWorkerHost.exe).  Without any special setup, you can monitor calls per minute, RAM/CPU utilization, database calls and external requests.  Beyond this, you'll want to use the .NET agent API:

https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api

Namely RecordMetric(), RecordResponseTimeMetric() and IncrementCounter() are available for Azure Worker Roles and other non-IIS applications.  Other methods in the API require proper HttpContext instances.